# Laravel 4 - Migrations 'Blueprint' meaning?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need a bit of advice.

I have a few migrations files in my setup.

In some of them im seeing the following code which arent in the rest and im not sure what its for

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
Schema::create('brand', function(Blueprint $table)
```

Could anyone tell me what the blueprint lines are for? as they arent in the other create table migrations.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because in your closure the parameter `$table` is tagged to be a `Blueprint` object. In fact every time a `Blueprint` is passed into the closure of `Schema::create`.
So you can restrict the parameter to `Blueprint` then PHP throws an fatal if an object of an other type is passed, or you can leave it blank so that PHP doesn't check the passed object.

Just look up the files where the `use`-Statement is missing. There will be no parameter constraint.

Comment: I was looking for this too. I didnt knew that PHP could do that. Since when is this possible?

Comment: This is possible since PHP5 and fully functional since PHP5.1.